# Getting undefined for setting a link MessageEmbed, Discord js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Getting with the embed something like this (why i get undefined?):

[image]

Code:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#f4f4f4')
            .setTitle('Twitter')
            .setDescription('Twitter Home Page')
            .addField(`https://twitter.com/home`)
             .setFooter('Twitter')
            msg.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `.addField()` incorrectly; `.addField("title", "description")` is the proper way to use this method!

I've amended the code for you:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#f4f4f4')
            .setTitle('Twitter')
            .setDescription('Twitter Home Page')
            .addField("Twitter Home Page", `[Click Here](https://twitter.com/home)`)
             .setFooter('Twitter')
            msg.channel.send(embed);
```

I've also made it a "masked link", which means you can click on text as if it were a link (`[text](link)` in embeds only) will work.

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks helped a lot

Comment: Make sure you've clicked on the green tick to accept this answer!